# Creating an image of an Android phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, disk-imaging

Does anyone know how to create a 1:1 disk image of an Android phone? I am taking a forensics course and our final project involves creating tools to recover information from a suspect's Android based phone, however to do this we need to be able to create a 1:1 image of the phone's disk for baseline comparisons. Also would the image be loadable into AVD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [nandroid](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=459830) — it will take a full image of each of an Android phone's partitions and return them to you as yaffs2 image files.

I haven't tried it personally, but you should be able to drop these directly into an AVD directory.  I can imagine you may have some issues with the hardware suddenly "changing" between a physical device and emulator, but it's worth a try...

Answer (score 0):

Check [nandroid](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=459830).

I have backed up my SDcard and mount it on AVD, but I am not completely sure you can mount the internal mem that nandroid backs up.